# Implementing like component in Angular 13 app

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a like mechanism in my project but I got stuck. Basically I am trying to do this: when the user clicks on the like button, it changes the colour of the like ('fills it') and displays the number of likes dynamically and if the page is refreshed i want it to still display the 'filled' like button like this:

[image]

The first part of this problem seems to work fine but after i reset the page it just goes back to this:

[image]

How can I make it so if I refresh my browser if it was liked to remain liked, and if its liked and I click it, to unlike? Here's some code I have tried:

**HTML**

```
<div class="likes">
        <div *ngIf="!isLiked">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o" (click)="likeTweet(tweet.id)"></i>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isLiked">
          <i class="fa fa-heart" (click)="unlikeTweet(tweet.id)"></i>
        </div>       
        <div class="likes-count">
        {{getLikes}}
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Component**

```
 isLiked: boolean = false;
 
    like: Like = new Like();

    likeTweet(tweetId: number){
      this.likeService.likeTweet(tweetId, this.like).subscribe(response => {
        this.like = response;
        this.isLiked = true;
      });
    }

    unlikeTweet(tweetId: number){
      this.likeService.unlikeTweet(tweetId).subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.isLiked = false;
      });
    }

    getTweetLikes(){
      const tweetId = this.route.snapshot.params['tweetId'];
      this.likeService.getTweetLikes(tweetId).subscribe(response => {
        this.likes = response;
      })
    } 
    likes: LikeModel[];

    get getLikes(){
      return this.likes.length;
    }
```

**Service**

```
  url: string = environment.apiBaseUrl; // localhost:8080
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  likeTweet(tweetId: number, like: Like){
    return this.http.post<Like>(`${this.url}/like/tweet/${tweetId}`,like);
  }
  unlikeTweet(tweetId: number){
    return this.http.delete<Like>(`${this.url}/unlike/tweet/${tweetId}`);
  }
  getTweetLikes(tweetId: number){
    return this.http.get<LikeModel[]>(`${this.url}/tweet/${tweetId}/likes`);
  }
```

**Entities**

```
export class Like {
    id: number;
    likedTweet: Tweet;
    likedComment: Comment;
    user: User;

}

export class LikeModel {
    username: string;
}
```

**relationship**
[image]

Comment: you have to store that information whether it was liked or not, for that you can have that info stored in backend, so that on the initial api call you get that piece of data.

Comment: @Kaneki21 Do you mean the controller in my backend? If yes i already got a LikeController that does that and saves the like in my database

Comment: yeah...some kind of relation has to be defined between the tweet and the user to define whether the user has liked it or not.

Comment: @Kaneki21 I have that kind of relationship already on the backend sure, i can update my post and  post a screenshot of my database

Comment: sure Ruchi...as you said you have a relation then ngoninit you can call for the check condition(if the tweet was liked by the user or not)...in my opinion you can also store the info for the user's state and check if the tweet was liked by the user...it will be more efficient

Comment: @Kaneki21 I tried something like that -> if(this.like.likedTweet.user === this.like.user) this.isLiked = true; but doesnt seem to work, also i debugged it using scopes and  my like: Like object is undefined

Comment: that has to be done in some lifecycle hook..ngoninit can be used..it will also depend on the flow of the component(api call)

Comment: @Kaneki21 I tried now using the likes: LikeModel[] array, and i saw that im receiving there the username of the user, and i compare it with the current user username and it seemed to work but, if i add *ngFor directive on my div class="likes" the icon dissapears, i think this happens because i unliked the post and there are 0 items in the array, any way to fix that so i dont have to remove the directive from my div?

Comment: don't put the condition on likes div...your current html should work fine if the isLiked variable is handled properly. 
Just a suggestion, you can use ngIf and else rather than 2 ngifs

Comment: @Kaneki21 I didnt put the condition div, i just did the following <div class="likes" *ngFor="let like of likes"> <div *ngIf="like.username !== user.username"> 'display empty heart' (click)="likeTweet(tweet.id)" <div *ngIf="like.username === user.username"> 'display filled heart' (click)="unlikeTweet(tweet.id)", but because the likes array doesn't contain any data (because i unliked the tweet)  the icon doesnt show up anymore

Comment: in that case keep a check before the ngfor that the length is more than 0 or not, but please check the flow once again and see if there are scopes to make things more efficient

Comment: @Kaneki21 I managed to solve that using ngOnInit as you said, now i am having a problem with displaying the tweet likes, because using the length method doesn't quite work, ive tried making a counter variable and increment it in likeTweet method and decrement it in unlikeTweet method, and then make a method and return that value and call it in ngOnInit and also adding it in my html template but if i refresh my browser it goes back again to 0 even if i liked the post, any idea on how to make this work?

Comment: do the API call to get likes count on ngoninit as well. that way on every page refresh you will get its value from backend. You have to use lifecycle hooks for handling the flow of your component.

Comment: @Kaneki21 Yeah i don t think i have on my backend any counter that manages the number of likes, i guess i have to implement it then and then get it through a http request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247096/discussion-between-kaneki21-and-ruschisb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruschisb,

In your function getTweetLikes() you need update property isLiked, because this is ever false.

Thank!